# Количество нечетных чисел

Tags: python

"Задан интервал целых чисел [b;e][b;e]. Вы должны написать программу, чтобы определить, сколько нечетных чисел принадлежит этому интервалу.

Обратите внимание, что интервал может быть достаточно большим, и решения, перебирающие все натуральные числа, не будут проходить часть тестов.

Формат входных данных
На вход в одной строке подается два целых числа bb и ee — границы интервала,  -10^{18}\leq b\leq e\leq 10^{18}−10
18
≤b≤e≤10
18
.

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести одно число — количество нечетных чисел в заданном интервале.

Методика проверки
Программа проверяется на 30 тестах. Прохождение каждого теста оценивается в 0.5 балла.  Тесты из условия задачи при проверке не используются.

Sample Input 1:
-3 8

Sample Output 1:
6

Sample Input 2:
0 0

Sample Output 2:
0"

Написала такой код:

```
b=int(input())
e=int(input())
if b%2==0 and e%2==0:
    a=e-b
    print(a//2)
elif b%2!=0 and e%2!=0:
    a=e-b+2
    print(a//2)
else:
    a=e-b+1
    print(a//2)
```

Вроде всё правильно, но почему-то когда высылаю его через stepik выдаёт Runtime error. Что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, но могу предположить, что причина может крыться в способе ввода данных. По условию "... На вход **в одной строке** подается два целых числа...". В вашем коде данные вводятся двумя `input()`. Попробуйте обработать ввод в одной строке

```
b, e = map(int, input().split())
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло